# Assigning an array value to a variable inside a for loop in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code (CODE 1) and it works fine. It simply assigns the product and its price to cells based on the value of the combo box. I thought of using a for each...loop to shorten the code in case my client has thousands of products.

CODE 2 is my experimental dig at this. However, when I assign the value of an array element to a variable inside the loop, VBA is giving me a run-time error 1004 type mismatch? Also, how do I could the for next...loop to accomplish my objective for a two dimensional array?

Can anyone help? I've been searching for answers all over for the past three days and I can't find any. Thanks :-)

```
''CODE 1
Private Sub Product1ComboBox_Change()

'Fills in Product and Price columns.
If Sheet1.Product1ComboBox.Value = "1-2-3 ABC" Then
    Sheet1.Range("H2").Value = "1-2-3 ABC"
    Sheet1.Range("I2").Value = "150.00"
ElseIf Sheet1.Product1ComboBox.Value = "1-3 Pick Up Sticks" Then
    Sheet1.Range("H2").Value = "1-3 Pick Up Sticks"
    Sheet1.Range("I2").Value = "89.00"
ElseIf Sheet1.Product1ComboBox.Value = "Meat and Potatoes" Then
    Sheet1.Range("H2").Value = "Meat and Potatoes"
    Sheet1.Range("I2").Value = "140.00"
ElseIf Sheet1.Product1ComboBox.Value = "Pigs in a Blanket" Then
    Sheet1.Range("H2").Value = "Pigs in a Blanket"
    Sheet1.Range("I2").Value = "140.00"
Else
    Sheet1.Range("H2").Value = "Simply Toasted"
    Sheet1.Range("I2").Value = "65.00"
End If

'Computes amount.
Sheet1.Range("J2").Value = Sheet1.Range("I2").Value * Sheet1.Qty1ComboBox.Value

End Sub

''CODE 2
Private Sub Product1ComboBox_Change()

Dim Products(1 To 5)
Dim i
Dim Product

Products(1) = "1-2-3 ABC--150"
Products(2) = "1-3 Pick Up Sticks--89"
Products(3) = "Meat and Potatoes--140"
Products(4) = "Pigs in a Blanket--140"
Products(5) = "Simply Toasted--65"

For Each i In Products
    Product = Products(i) 'PROBLEM: RUN-TIME ERROR 13 TYPE MISMATCH.
    If Products(i) = Sheet1.Product1ComboBox.Value Then
        Sheet1.Range("H2").Value = Products(i) 'PROBLEM: RUN-TIME ERROR 13 TYPE MISMATCH.
    Exit For
    End If
Next i

'Computes amount.
Sheet1.Range("J2").Value = Sheet1.Range("I2").Value * Sheet1.Qty1ComboBox.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `For Each i In Products`

What this does is assign the value of each element of `Products` to `i` in turn.  Then when you use `Products(i)` you are in effect saying, eg `Products("1-2-3 ABC--150")` which is of cource nonsence.

Try instead

```
For i = LBound(Products) to UBound(Products)
```

or

```
For Each Product In Products
    If Product = Sheet1.Product1ComboBox.Value Then
        Sheet1.Range("H2").Value = Product
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight Chris. I re-wrote my code using the hint you gave and it worked flawlessly. Now I need to do it on a two-dimensional array to factor in the price of the product. Here is the code that now works: For i = LBound(Products) To UBound(Products)
    If Sheet1.Product1ComboBox.Value = Products(i) Then
        Sheet1.Range("H2").Value = Products(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

Comment: Glad to have helped. You should now take a moment to understand how SO works. Accept answers that you consider answers your question. Research first (there are many answers on SO about 2D arrays) and if still stuck ask another question